# Encoder-Decoder noise problem after decoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder, encoder-decoder

I have an array of size (12960, ) and I'm using very simple dense autoencoder architecture to reproduce array as shown below.

```
input_img = Input(shape=(12960,))

encoded = Dense(units=2000, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded = Dense(units=12960, activation='relu')(encoded)
```

Now I'm using 20 epoch and 64 batch size to train the model.

But I'm getting some kind of noise(or 0 value) at many places when I plot the array after decoding. I have attached original and decoded image below. Can someone explain me why this is happening. I'm new to deep learning so I don't have much idea about it's working. Is it because I'm using very simple architecture or I'm compressing a lot while encoding?

[image: Original]

[image: Decoded]

Comment: could you try leaky_relu instead of relu?

Comment: Your net is a simple feed-forward net, no autoencoder.
You may have a look at the tensorflow [tutorial][1] in autoencoder, if interested:

It would be helpful to have more information about the training process, like accuracy, your training set and the whole model structure

  [1]: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae

Comment: @tritsu hey it did work better, thank you so much. Can you explain me why it worked better than relu?

Comment: @Chris_007 I moved it to the answer with the explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LeakyReLU instead of ReLU.

It might be because since ReLU is defined as `ReLU(x) = max(0, x)`, for negative values ReLU always returns 0.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but in my array I don't have any negative values.

Comment: @Chris_007 It seems that the weights and biases could be negative in your model. Even if your data has no negative values. (I's assuming you are calling the data as array.)